# Symfony 2 returns wrong url with proxy

Tags: php, symfony, proxy, twig, silex

I'm working on an Silex project and run into an issue with wrong url's when calling the site with a proxy.

Sitename without proxy: http://sitename.com/someFile.php

Sitename with proxy: https://sslsites.com/sitename.com/someFile.php

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST']: 'sslsites.com'
```

I set the Trusted Proxies in my index.php

```
Request::setTrustedProxies(array('sslsites.com'));
```

composer.json

```
"silex/silex": "1.0.*@dev",
"twig/twig": "~1.12",
"symfony/twig-bridge": "~2.2",
"symfony/validator": "~2.2",
"symfony/form": "~2.2",
"symfony/config": "~2.2",
"symfony/translation": "~2.2",
"symfony/locale": "~2.2",
"symfony/yaml": "~2.2",
"symfony/filesystem": "~2.2",
"symfony/finder": "~2.2",
"swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "~4.3",
"doctrine/dbal": "~2.3"
```

When running "url('category')" in a twig-Template, i'd expect:

```
https://sslsites.com/sitename.com/category
```

But I see instead

```
https://sslsites.com/category
```

I don't want a quick and dirty solution. Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

When using the component as part of the framework you can the `router.request_context.base_url` parameter, like so..

```
parameters:
    router.request_context.base_url: my/path
```

Which would lead me to believe that you would be able to use..

```
if ($baseUrl = $app['request']->server->get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST')) {
    $app['request_context']->setBaseUrl($baseUrl);
}
```

I assume the best place to do this would be when you are creating the app but I may be wrong as I've only had a cursory glance at Silex.

Comment: Thanks for your anser, but it didn't worked for me.

**Fatal error**:  Call to a member function get() on a non-object

You forgot a parenthesis in your if-Statement

Comment: Maybe it's `$app['request']` rather than `$request` and actually I think you can use `$app['request_context']`. Have updated.